# how to clear map in awk?

Tags: dictionary, awk

I have a file a.txt.
There are many numbers in each line in a.txt:

```
1 2 3 1 2
5 6 7 7
19 20 20
```

I have to print each line without duplicate numbers, just like following results:

```
1 2 3
5 6 7
19 20
```

I use map in awk, but must clear map each time.
I don't know how to clear map in awk when reading each line.

```
awk '{ split($0, arr, " "); \
for(i=1;i<=length(arr);i++){dup_map[arr[i]]=1;} \
for(num in dup_map){printf("%s ", num);} printf("\n"); clear dup_map; } \
}' a.txt
```

Could someone tell me how to clear map in awk ?

Answer (score 5):

gawk has a function `delete` for this:

```
delete array
```

In awk this can be achieved by

```
split("", array)
```

> The split function (see section Built-in Functions for String
> Manipulation) clears out the target array first. This call asks it to
> split apart the null string. Since there is no data to split out, the
> function simply clears the array and then returns.

Both options mentioned in the [**gawk online manual**](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Delete.html).

Comment: `split("",array)` to init an array hasn't been required for several years since `delete(array)` became part of POSIX. If the version of awk you're using requires that then you need to get a more current awk version (preferably gawk) as it's probably missing a lot of other functionality.

Comment: @EdMorton ...thus, you may wonder that I even noted this "new-fashion gawk" stuff and even as first option...

Answer (score 1):

This is THE right way to do what you want:

```
$ awk '{
    delete(seen)
    for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
        if ( !seen[$i]++ ) {
            printf "%s%s", (i>1 ? OFS : ""), $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}' file
1 2 3
5 6 7
19 20
```

Note the idiomatic use of an array named `seen` to keep track of which `$i` values have been seen before and that the fields will be printed in the order they occurred (you have other answers that will randomize their order by use of the `in` operator) and that there will be no trailing blank char printed at the end of each line (you have answers that do that too).

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{split("",M);for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i in M)$i="";else M[$i]++;$0=$0}7' YourFile
```

Notes:

```
awk '# for non empty lines
   /./ {
      # reset array Map
      split( "", Map)
      # for each field (separtor is space)
      for( i=1; i<=NF ;i++) {
         # if the field content is in map, set it to empty string
         # if not, add it to the map
         if( $i in Map) $i=""
          else Map[ $i]++
         }
      # rewrite the line for single separator (not mandatory)
      $0=$0
      }
   # print the resulting line (default action)
   7 { print }
   ' YourFile
```

Comment: `split("",array)` to init an array hasn't been required for several years since `delete(array)` became part of POSIX. If the version of awk you're using requires that then you need to get a more current awk version (preferably gawk) as it's probably missing a lot of other functionality.

Comment: on my AIX:  `>>>  delete( <<<
 awk: 0602-502 The statement cannot be correctly parsed`, on my linux (gawk), no problem

Comment: Then you need to stop using that awk since it's not POSIX compliant and who knows what else might not work? RE intervals? Character classes? Other?

Comment: still have hundred of server with that and need to work with :-(. linux is coming from the North ...

Answer (score -1):

note that you don't need the initial splitting, since `awk` already splits fields for you,

```
$ awk '{delete a; 
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; 
        for(k in a) printf "%s ", k; 
        print ""}' file

1 2 3
5 6 7
19 20
```

or, with deleting entries instead of the array

```
$ awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; 
        for(k in a) 
          {printf "%s ", k; delete a[k]} 
        print ""}' file
```